# Why adding an invisible uninteractive overlay increases performance of scroll synchronization? [Chrome]

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, scroll

I need to synchronise the scroll of two elements: A content area and a "header".

But when I used the `scroll` event to change the position of the other element with a CSS `transform`, there was a notable delay between the user scrolling and the header moving, which is distracting, specially on Chrome.

However, when comparing to other applications that use the same method for synchronising the scroll position, they didn't have it. After many hours trying to find why, I've finally found it: they have an invisible overlay that covers the whole scroll area, which is also not interactive (CSS `pointer-events: none`)

I've prepared a playground below, where the overlay is visible and doesn't cover the whole area so it can be compared easily.

At least this behaviour is happening in my machine, a Mac with Chrome, and I scroll through the trackpad gesture. There also needs to be some load, so this snippet also adds a 30ms blocking loop every 100ms to simulate one

```js
const content = document.getElementById("content");
const header = document.getElementById("header");

// Add content
const helloes = new Array(100).fill("Hello!").join("<br /><br />");
header.innerHTML = content.innerHTML = helloes;

// Synchronize scroll of content to header by adding `transform`
content.addEventListener("scroll", (evt) => {
  header.style.transform = `translateY(${-content.scrollTop}px)`;
});

// Simulates performance hit, either low-end computer or a component doing extra load
setInterval(() => {
  let start = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() < start + 30);
}, 120);
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.main>div {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#content {
  padding-right: 200px;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 160px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div id="header">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
  </div>

  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

As it can be quite tricky to reproduce, I've recorded this behaviour in this image

[image: Scroll performance demo]

It's quite subtle, but as you can see, when I'm scrolling with the mouse over the scroll area, there's a visible lag. If I'm scrolling instead on top of the uninteractive overlay, the scroll synchronization is perfect.

However, I totally can't understand why this happens - What is the reason adding an overlay and scrolling with the mouse on top of it improves the performance?

Comment: https://ryanseddon.com/css/pointer-events-60fps/

Comment: it makes no difference with firefox wherevere you set the mouse to scroll the boxes  ,  My computer is not a slow machine either ;)

Comment: @Andreas I think this might be it - I don't fully understand the article you linked, but scrolling on the scroll area shows 60fps, whereas scrolling on the overlay shows ~35fps. What I think it's happening is that the scroll event can't keep up on 60fps because the main thread is blocked by 30ms every 120ms, so visually it lags behind. Essentially you see the native scroll at 60fps and the synchronized at 35-40fps. With 30fps, the main thread is able to keep up with the renderer, so both line up perfectly.

Comment: The main purpose is to stop some events from happening (like hover) which could force the browser to re-draw/-paint the window.